# How can i train HMM for continuous sign language recognition

Tags: machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-models, accord.net

Currently i can recognize isolated words using HMM through training an HMM model for each sign, and for a new word i take the sign for the model giving the highest likelihood.

When it comes to multiple words joint together, i don't know what to do?
I know i should use **Viterbi** algorithm but i don't know how specially i don't know the start and end of each sign in the continuous stream also there're some unpredictable movements that come from the movement between the end of a sign and the start of the next sign

I'm using C# Accord.Net Library.

to be more specific my question is:

How can i train the HMM classifier to automatically decode the continuous sequence of "words" (and note that each one of the hmms represents a word) taking into consideration that in a live stream not every segment of a sequence is a word, some segments aren't words, if this is done through Viterbi algorithm , what's the supposed sequence of hidden states how can i get it, as based on my limited info the sequence length of hidden states is equal to the sequence length of observed states, and in this case each hidden state (word) will emit a sequence of observed points.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right now, the framework doesn't offer a way to segment the time sequences automatically. A common way to do that is using a gesture segmentation network based on HMMs and threshold models. This method was described in a 1999 paper entitled "An HMM-based threshold model approach for gesture recognition" by Lee and Kim. I have implemented most of the machinery necessary for making those models work, including the threshold models and some on-line implementations for HMMs, but unfortunately I hadn't finished implementing the detection network. It shouldn't be that difficult to do it now, though

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
You mean by building the network, to build the threshold model and compare its output with the HMM classifier maximum probability, and whenever a model log probability is greater than that of threshold model, then there's a word  right ?

Comment: Currently i've a problem with with balancing the threshold model with the output probabilities of the models for different signs , i mean by balancing choosing appropriate sample per class and choosing a suitable sensitivity value for the threshold model.
The threshold usually dominates and when it doesn't the learning error is so high, my sample data set each one is 6 dimension and the average length = 50 frame